# How to redirect to action result from timer elapsed event in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I  have scenario where i need to redirect to new action result on timer elapsed event, here is my code, its not working currently.

```
   public ActionResult ExistingClientConfirmation(AppointmentRequest model, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var appointment = AppointmentRequest.GetCurrent();

          try
            {
                if (!ValidateAppointmentNotBooked(appointment))
                {
                    return indexAction(appointment);
                }
                ValidateSession(appointment);
                if (collection != null)
                {
                    model.TimeInterval = collection["hdnTimeInterval"];
                    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, appointment);
                    aTimer.Interval = 5000;
                    aTimer.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (model != null)
                {
                    appointment.TimeInterval = model.TimeInterval;
                    appointment.Client = model.Client;
                }
                return RedirectToAction("ExistingClientConfirmation");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleAndRedirectException(ex);
            }
        }

 public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e,AppointmentRequest appointment)
        {
            HomePage(appointment);
        }

        public ActionResult HomePage(AppointmentRequest appointment)
        {
            return indexAction(appointment);
        }
```

during debug i saw its hitting the elapsed event for every five seconds, but not redirecting. Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: returning to same action is not possible `i guess` . i don't see any relevance why you doing like that (trying to create infinite loop if it works) .

Comment: hi have a timer in client side, i am restricting the user to book appointment in 10 minutes, otherwise it will expires and redirect to home page, its working fine in all browsers etc., i faced a problem when i try to open the same appointment in two different tab of same browser in mobile, only active tab the timer is running, after booking the appointment for a selected slot, i should not allow, in my case after completing the booking in active tab if i open the click the second tab its resuming from the place where i stopped and allowing the user to book. need to stop.

Comment: timers won't work like that. A controller method can't call the browser when some event happens (look at your OnTimedEvent - where would the result from your Homepage() controller action go? OnTimedEvent has no return type). You could store your expiration time somewhere in the current session (your HTTP context has a Session object you can use to store all kinds of information) and retrieve that value within each controller action. There you can react depending on the situation (expired/still valid).

Comment: you are right, but i am looking for to automate the time expiration. Thanks for your input, i found some workaround, keeping first active time in session and comparing the timer value, if not redirecting. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my comment, you can't return an action result from a timer event. The client has already received the result from the controller and your timer event has nothing to return to. So your timer event would fire, the method Homepage() would be executed and the result would be thrown away.

The http context has a session object that you can use to store all kinds of objects, for instance the expiration date. You can access the current session from your controller methods. Store the date there, retrieve it in your controller actions and act depending on the situation. That would also work when the user reloads a page or opens a second tab. Closing and reopening the browser (or tab) will create a new session, effectively resetting your session timer.